# check which image has been set to imageview

Tags: iphone

I have used the animated images on image view concept. It is working fine.Now whenever when I touch that image view I want to check which image is placed on that image view. How should I do this. I have used the following code to make the images animated.

```
addimage.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Softindia.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"],
                          nil];

addimage.animationDuration=25.0;
addimage.animationRepeatCount=0;

[addimage startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:addimage];
```

Now what should I do on the touch event of image view. Please provide me some solution to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are u facing problem in detecting touch or in getting image view name?

Comment: yup, I am unable to detect image name on its touch event..

Comment: did you tried the solution that i provide you?

Comment: I can't do that. Because i am setting the uiimageView image by using addimage.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Softindia.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"],
                          nil];
Then how could i setdescription to the image.

Comment: i have edited my answer. please check it

Comment: there is no method like setdescription name..

Comment: i am sorry!! it was a read only property!! i am changed the logic check whether it is useful or not

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
        [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagetap)] autorelease];
        [imgview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


-(void)imagetap
{
   // your code what ever you want on touch
}
```

Comment: How could I compare which image is located on image view at the time of tap.

Comment: How to get image name on the touch event ?

Answer (score 0):

I am affraid that there is no such property inside UIImage which help you to find image name.
you can use this tricky method for solving your problem.

create an property

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * imageArray;
```

and then synthesis in .m file

```
@synthesis imageArray
```

afterward perform following action

```
self.imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
UIImage *myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Softindia.png"];
[imageArray addObject:myImage1];

//Add Second Image
UIImage *myImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"];
[imageArray addObject:myImage2];

addimage.animationImages= imageArray;
```

and where ever you are getting your image check do following action

```
UIImage image = addimage.image;
 index = [imageArray indexOfObject:image];
 if(index == 0){
  //Do action for softindia.png
 }
 else {
  //Do action for images.png;
 }
```